# Allowing multiple logins from one account with ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd, instant-messaging

I have just started getting my hands dirty with building IM applications with ejabberd XMPP server and I have a requirement to allow one user account to login simultaneously from multiple devices and be able to follow conversations on all their logged in devices much like what gives in Skype, FB.

Is this possible with ejabberd out of the box or are there any further customizations one has to do?

Any pointers I can get woild be helpful. The body of knowledge out there is quite huge and knowing where to start looking has been quite daunting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, connecting from multiple devices at once is part of the XMPP standard. In a JID, the "resource" portion (*e.g.:* the part after the slash in `jome@stackoverflow.com/desktop`) is unique to a single connection and users may have many resources. So the resource could be your MAC or some unique device ID.

Vanilla XMPP allows users to specify priorities with each resource, and messages are routed to the highest-priority resource present. To follow a conversation across all resources at once, you need to enable [XEP-0280](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html).